# Label display inside nodes cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape-web

Is there a way to display a node label centered inside the node such as cytoscape desktop does by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can control this with the `labelValign` property as explained in [the Wiki StyleObject description](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/wiki/StyleObject). For example:

```js
var myStyle = {
    selectors: {
        "node": {
            labelValign: "middle",
            ... } } }

$("#cy").cy({style: myStyle, ... })
```

Answer (score 17):

I set css style for nodes and it works:

```
"text-valign" : "center"
"text-halign" : "center"
```

Comment: I am not sure if I want to upvote or downvote. text-valign and text-halign really DO work, however they are certainly not css properties.

Comment: This works, but they are cytoscape-js styles though.

Answer (score 0):

From the official and actual documentation - text-valign and text-halign are the way to go. They are certainly not css properties however. The possible options are: text-halign - left, center, or right; text-valign - top, center, or bottom.

These options work only for nodes, not for edges.

[Offical documentation for more info](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels)